# Mercurial Messing Up csproj Files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mercurial, merge

I am using Hg to manage and merge code with three other developers involved in a VS2008 project. We do have an .hgignore file that ignores a fair number of files not necessary to track, such as *.pdb, *.obj, etc. However, we do track .csproj files.

Periodically, it would seem that files go missing after a merge. We would get build issues, and have to relocate files which were in the project folders, but not in the csproj file.

Eventually, I noted during a merge conflict that sometimes Hg seems to merge incorrectly. Here's a screenshot below. The actual conflict that requires manual intervention is lower in the file. But in this section, hg incorrectly replaces DirectoryTasks.cs with a new, different file called ReportTasks.cs, when in fact, both should be added. How do people manage to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: I see the letter `B` in the left column near `ReportTasks.cs` line, which you selected `B` there (or does it mark automatic decisions in the same way?!). Instead of selecting `A` and `B`

Comment: No, hg selected B before I did anything. The actual conflict is somewhere else in the file, waiting for my resolution. IOW, I did not select B at this merge location, it was somehow "preselected" that way and will lead to a bad build...

Comment: To be clearer, the screenshot is what I see when starting the merge resolution, with some stuff already merged for me. I have not yet taken an action on this file.

Comment: @alphadogg - can you replace screenshot with only relevant part of window and bigger scale?

Comment: Although closed, and the example is bad, there seems to be a possibility of csproj files being an issue in CVSes. See http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.288423.10 for an old, different example. VS seems to add <compile> lines in some way that can lead to merge issues.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is shown on the picture means:

1. There was `DirectoryTasks.cs` line originally
2. Then developer 1 manually or using some VS GUI (in parent1 revision) changed it to `ReportTasks.cs`
3. Developer 2 didn't change it

So when you merge - you get the changes made by another developer.

The question should be: why VS or developer replaced `DirectoryTasks` with `ReportTasks` in `parent1` revision (and it is not related to HG at all)

Comment: There was no change of file. Dev 1 ADDED ReportTasks.cs. DirectoryTasks.cs was always there. (In fact, you see it in the Base column.) For some reason, the textual compare seems to think they are the same line?

Comment: @alphadogg: nope, I see that developer 1 added interface and **replaced** cs-file. And hg sees the same as I

Comment: @alphadogg: what if you update to `parent1` and try finding `DirectoryTasks.cs` in the project file? What line is it?

Comment: Looks like the files are there but a csproj lost reference to it in one of the branches at some point. Hence my confusion. Seems like the merge itself is "correct", but working from an out-of-whack state. I will research this further.

Comment: @alphadogg: just a side note: I've been working with VS2010 and hg and hadn't experienced such erorrs

Comment: Looks like files in the directories aren't matching up to files in the csproj file. I think I have other issues than hg and merges. Devs seem to be mucking in the csproj files, making them go out of sync with folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'll support zerkms: it's developer's hands fault, not hg

Author of parent1 **replaced** one string `DirectoryTasks` by `ReportTasks` and **added** another `ReportTasks` string. You have to work **with developer** in such cases.

Is .csproj file mandatory in order to get functioning project in a totally new workplace or it's local IDE-artifact, which each IDE recreates for own needs?

Comment: It is mandatory (it is the equivalent of a makefile) but it is managed using the IDE, rather than as a text file.  It can go wrong if a developer edits the project and updates working copy in source control without saving the project.  You're then given the option to use the in-memory copy or the on-disk copy.  Neither of these options are good as they both lose changes.  It is good practice to ensure that you save the project as soon as you make changes to it (although there is no "save project" button so you have to use "save all").